# AmpScript for PrePopulate based on previous submitted values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to build the backbone of a form where I will have the values in the form pre-populated based on previous submissions. If there is a submission in my DE then I want the values from the last submission; if there is no submission for that specific contact I want the values in the form to be blanked out:

Code that I have written so far to achieve this is:

```
   %%[var @SubscriberKey,@email,@date
SET @SubscriberKey=RequestParameter('SubscriberKey')
SET @email=RequestParameter('email')

SET @rows=LookupOrderedRows('Preference Centre-Cris',1,'DateSubmitted DESC','Contact ID',@SubscriberKey)


if rowcount(@rows)>0 then
SET @row = ROW(@rows, 1)

SET @ModeMail = FIELD(@row,"mode-mail")
SET @ModeMailUserInput = FIELD(@row,"mode-mail--user-input")
SET @ModeEmail = FIELD(@row,"mode-email")
SET @ModeEmailUserInput = FIELD(@row,"mode-email--user-input")
SET @InterestPlaces = FIELD(@row,"interest-places")
SET @InterestPeople = FIELD(@row,"interest-people")
SET @InterestThings = FIELD(@row,"interest-things")
SET @InterestFood = FIELD(@row,"interest-food")
SET @InterestCommunity = FIELD(@row,"interest-community")
SET @InterestStories= FIELD(@row,"interest-stories")
SET @InterestTips= FIELD(@row,"interest-tips")
SET @SpecialDate=FIELD(@row,"special-date")
SET @SpecialMonth=FIELD(@row,"special-month")
SET @SpecialYear=FIELD(@row,"special-year")
SET @PlacesEurope=FIELD(@row,"places-europe")
SET @PlacesSouthAmerica=FIELD(@row,"places-south-america")
SET @PlacesNorthCentralAmerica=FIELD(@row,"places-north-central-america")
SET @PlacesAfricaMiddleEast=FIELD(@row,"places-africa-middle-east")
SET @PlacesAUSNZ=FIELD(@row,"places-australia-new-zealand")
SET @PlacesAsia=FIELD(@row,"places-asia")
SET @PlacesOthers=FIELD(@row,"places-others")
SET @TravelMonth=FIELD(@row,"travel-month")
SET @TravelYear=FIELD(@row,"travel-year")
SET @Frequency=FIELD(@row,"frequency")
SET @History=FIELD(@row,"history")
SET @HistoryUserInput=FIELD(@row,"history--user-input")
SET @UnsubReason=FIELD(@row,"unsub-reason")
SET @UnsubReasonUserInput=FIELD(@row,"unsub-reason--user-input")
SET @DateSubmitted=FIELD(@row,"DateSubmitted")
SET @DateFormatted=FormatDate(@DateSubmitted,"dddd MMMM YYYY HH:MM")

else

SET @ModeMail = "false"
SET @ModeMailUserInput = ""
SET @ModeEmail = "false"
SET @ModeEmailUserInput = "false"
SET @InterestPlaces = "false"
SET @InterestPeople = "false"
SET @InterestThings = "false"
SET @InterestFood = "false"
SET @InterestCommunity = "false"
SET @InterestStories= "false"
SET @InterestTips= "false"
SET @SpecialDate= ""
SET @SpecialMonth=""
SET @SpecialYear=""
SET @PlacesEurope="false"
SET @PlacesSouthAmerica="false"
SET @PlacesNorthCentralAmerica="false"
SET @PlacesAfricaMiddleEast="false"
SET @PlacesAUSNZ="false"
SET @PlacesAsia="false"
SET @PlacesOthers=""
SET @TravelMonth=""
SET @TravelYear=""
SET @Frequency=""
SET @History=""
SET @HistoryUserInput=""
SET @UnsubReason=""
SET @UnsubReasonUserInput=""
endif]%%
<br>
    Values of your last submission on %%=v(@DateFormatted)=%%

For Interest: %%=v(@InterestPlaces)=%%
<br>
For South America: %%=v(@PlacesSouthAmerica)=%%
<br>
For Europe: %%=v(@PlacesEurope)=%%
    <br>
Special Date: %%=v(@SpecialDate)=%%
 <br>
Special Month: %%=v(@SpecialMonth)=%%
```

The situation i am is that regardless if there was a submission or not all of my values get blanked with the false value.

I am not sure what did I miss in the code?!

Any help is appreciated.

Giulietta

[image]

Comment: Does the form display the attributes correctly when a submission is loaded?

Comment: nope. I get the false value shown even when I have a submission. Please see print screen attached. for the record which i am trying to populate the form i have True values in there and should show True.

Comment: How are you passing the parameters? Can you try printing the values of subscriber keg and email address to be sure the variables aren’t blank?

Answer (score 0):

The "if rowcount(@rows)>0 then" statement is checking to see if a row exists that matches your lookup criteria, where 'Contact ID' = @SubscriberKey, and then it will return the **entire row** - regardless of empty/null values.
You can enforce default values by checking each value in the returned rowset. For your first 2 values (lines 11 & 12 in your code) you can do this:

```
SET @ModeMail = IIF(EMPTY(FIELD(@row,"mode-mail")),"false",FIELD(@row,"mode-mail"))
SET @ModeMailUserInput = IIF(EMPTY(FIELD(@row,"mode-mail--user-input")),"",FIELD(@row,"mode-mail--user-input"))
```

This will check the value returned in each column, and if it's empty, then use the default values of "false" or "".
You can read more about the [EMPTY()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm) and [IIF()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm) functions to see how they work.